# Updating an array without index

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was unsure how exactly to phrase this in the title. I've made a todo list and I'm working on making the todo items editable. Through the `displayTodo` function, I've been able to make the `li` items editable in the DOM, but I would like this change to be reflected in the `todoList` array as well when I hit the save button. I'm unsure of how exactly I would be able to make this work. I was thinking of the splice method, but I don't know how that would work in this situation since I would need to pass in the index.

```js
// Global Variables
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
const removeBtn = document.querySelector('.remove-btn');
const todos = document.querySelector('.todos');

// Event Listeners 
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addTodo);
removeBtn.addEventListener('click', removeTodo);

const todoList = [

]

function addTodo() {
  // Push user input to array
  let inputValue = input.value;
  todoList.push(inputValue);
  displayTodo();
  input.value = '';
  console.log(todoList);
}

function removeTodo() {
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.todos li');
  // Remove last todo from array
  todoList.splice(-1, 1);
  // Remove last todo from ul
  todos.removeChild(listItems[listItems.length - 1]);
  //console.log(todoList);
}

function displayTodo() {
  // Create li and display it
  let newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.textContent = input.value;
  todos.appendChild(newTodo);
  // Create edit button and display it
  let editButton = document.createElement('button');
  editButton.textContent = 'Edit';
  newTodo.appendChild(editButton);
  editButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Create edit input and save button
    editButton.style.opacity = 0;
    editButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    let editInput = document.createElement('input');
    newTodo.appendChild(editInput);
    let saveButton = document.createElement('button');
    newTodo.appendChild(saveButton);
    saveButton.textContent = 'Save';
    saveButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      newTodo.textContent = editInput.value;
      console.log(todoList);
    })
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Add A Task" autocomplete="off" required>
    <button class="add-btn">Add Task</button>
    <button class="remove-btn">Remove Task</button>
    <ul class="todos">

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, In `editButton.addEventListener('click', function() {}`, get the text content of the `<li>` element that has to be edited. The text content has the word 'Edit' appended to the list element and hence removing it in the second line. Get the index of the array element whole value is `liValue` using `indexOf` property.

```
let liValue = newTodo.textContent;
liValue = liValue.replace('Edit', '');
let liIndex = todoList.indexOf(liValue);
```

In `saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {}`, after updating the DOM, use `splice()` to update the array list.

```
todoList.splice(liIndex, 1, editInput.value);
```

---

I have added the function in which the changes are done. The parts of the code that has to be added are commented down below.

```
editButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // Create edit input and save button
    editButton.style.opacity = 0;
    editButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /* first part of the code starts here */
    let liValue = newTodo.textContent;
    liValue = liValue.replace('Edit', '');
    let liIndex = todoList.indexOf(liValue);
    /* first part of the code ends here */

    let editInput = document.createElement('input');
    newTodo.appendChild(editInput);
    let saveButton = document.createElement('button');
    newTodo.appendChild(saveButton);
    saveButton.textContent = 'Save';
    saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        newTodo.textContent = editInput.value;

        /* second part of the code starts here */
        todoList.splice(liIndex, 1, editInput.value);
        /* second part of the code ends here */
    })
});
```

---

> Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/geekyquentin/pen/LYQdjXw